# IIS URL Rewrite Rule Ignored when Path is Part of Virtual Directory

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, url-rewriting

I'm attempting to create a URL rewrite rule in IIS that redirects a user to a new web page. The path for the rule is a deleted PDF file that was contained in a virtual directory. I have this rule working on an existing site, but on our new/updated website using .Net core - the rule does not work (returns a 404 status code). The virtual directory setup is the same - /pdf. It appears that the rule is completely ignored if it is a virtual directory.

```
Website
│   New_Web_Page
└───pdf (virtual directory)
│   │   A_PDF_File.pdf
```

```xml
<rule name="PDF Redirect Rule" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="pdf/A_PDF_File.pdf" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="New_Web_Page" redirectType="Permanent"  />
</rule>
```

Comment: if the url rewriting is important to your business, I think you should try delegating that task to `asp.net core` middleware. Relying on `IIS` can be familiar with your team but of course it's not flexible such as when your app need to be deployed using another host type, e.g: `docker`. Of course this is a bit off-sided from what you want with `IIS` anyway.

Comment: Unfotunately this site has multiple applications. The other web applications are of asp.net web forms and rely on some of these virtual directories to function. Our goal is to eventually eliminate these legacy applications when we have time to rewrite them (or include them in the newer site).

Answer (score 0):

Placing a web.config file within the virtual directory with the appropriate rewrite rule fixes the issue. The rule will need to be changed to match the placement of the file. The rule is:

```xml
<rule name="PDF Redirect Rule" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="A_PDF_File.pdf" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/New_Web_Page" redirectType="Permanent"  />
</rule>
```

And the directory now looks like this:

```
Website
│   New_Web_Page
└───pdf (virtual directory)
│   │   A_PDF_File.pdf
│   │   web.config
```